# Get last insert id after a prepared insert with PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm using PHP PDO with PostgreSQL for a new project.

Given the following function, how can I return the id of the row just inserted?
It doesn't work the way it looks now.

```
function adauga_administrator($detalii) {
    global $db;
    $ultima_logare = date('Y-m-d');

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO site_admins (sa_nume, sa_prenume, sa_user_name, sa_password, sa_email, sa_id_rol, sa_status, sa_ultima_logare) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $detalii['nume']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $detalii['prenume']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $detalii['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, md5(md5($detalii['parola'] . SIGURANTA_PAROLE) . SIGURANTA_PAROLE));
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $detalii['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $detalii['rol'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $detalii['status'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(8, $ultima_logare);    
    $stmt->execute(); 

    $id = $db->lastInsertId();
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: Also call like - `return $db->lastInsertId($stmt); `

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

> Returns the ID of the last inserted
>   row, or the last value from a sequence
>   object, depending on the underlying
>   driver. For example, PDO_PGSQL()
>   requires you to specify the name of a
>   sequence object for the name
>   parameter.

It should be something like:

```
return $db->lastInsertId('yourIdColumn');
```

[EDIT] Update link to doc

Comment: I tried with the sequence name as an argument for lastInsertId() and it works. Thanks.

Comment: What is the sequence name? The name of the column which contains the autoincremented value?

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm sequences are used in Postgres rather then MySQL. MySQL will usually return without a parameter being passed (granted you have a primary key).

Comment: `\d tablename` showed me `id         | integer           | not null default nextval('addr_source_id_seq'::regclass)`, I put `addr_source_id_seq` and voila! So in my case it wasn't `table_column_seq` line.

Answer (score 11):

From the PHP [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

> For example, PDO_PGSQL() requires you
> to specify the name of a sequence
> object for the name parameter.

You could also use [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) in the INSERT-statement and fetch the INSERT-result like a SELECT result.

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers are not very clear (PDO doc too)

In postgreSQL, sequences are created when you are using the `SERIAL` data type.

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients (
  id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name       varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

So the sequence name will be `ingredients_id_seq`

```
$db->lastInsertId('ingredients_id_seq');
```