# lastInsertId does not work in Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, lastinsertid

I am using Postgresql, when I want to use PDO to retrieve the latest insertion ID, I got a problem. Here is my code:

```
$db->lastInsertId('columnName');
```

The error message says

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "columnName" does not exist
```

I guess I have some misunderstanding about "sequence object" stated in the PHP Manual.

```
Note:

Returns the ID of the last inserted row, or the last value from a sequence object, 
depending on the underlying driver. For example, PDO_PGSQL() requires you to specify the 
name of a sequence object for the name parameter.
```

Currently, the "columnName" is the string of that auto-incremented attribute. Can anyone point out where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last insert id after a prepared insert with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057954/get-last-insert-id-after-a-prepared-insert-with-pdo)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses [sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html) to generate values for [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) columns and `serial` columns are generally what is used for "auto-incrementing" columns in PostgreSQL. Sequences have names and are, in general, independent of any particular table so you could have one sequence generating unique IDs for several different tables; the sequence name is what [`lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) wants as its argument:

> For example, **PDO_PGSQL()** requires you to specify the name of a sequence object for the ***name*** parameter.

The sequence object created by PostgreSQL is automatically named `[table]_[column]_seq`, So:

```
$id = $db->lastInsertId('tableName_columnName_seq');
```

Comment: doesn't work that way. PGSQL "requires" a parameter to indicate the sequence object. If you leave it blank, nothing is returned.

Comment: @Michael: Then you need to know the name of the sequence. The default would be `t_c_seq` where `t` is the table name and `c` is the column name. This requirement is rather bizarre though. I don't have all the PHP/PostgreSQL set up ATM so I can't verify any of this myself.

Comment: table_column_seq, this is it! Thanks you!

Comment: @Michael: You could also look at [`INSERT ... RETURNING id`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) and bypass `lastInsertId` completely.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue today, lastInsertId() was only returning false.  Found the answer that solved my issue on a different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31638196/1477123

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients (
    id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name       varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

So the sequence name will be ingredients_id_seq

```
$db->lastInsertId('ingredients_id_seq');
```

Answer (score 1):

So the **sequence name** will be `ingredients_id_seq`,

```
$db->lastInsertId('ingredients_id_seq');
```

This format actually solved my issues!!!

Comment: you can also use $db->nextval();

Answer (score -1):

Use sequence name instead column name

```
$db->lastInsertId('columnName');
```