# Grab last ID of Insert query

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysql-insert-id

I need to get the story_id from the last insert. Ive tried using `mysql_insert_id()` but it doesn't seem to work with my statement. Here is the code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO active_stories (story_id, current_chapter, creator, cover_title, cover_img_name, create_date, last_update_date, story_tags, locked) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("issssssi",$zero, $creatorName,$storyTitle, $fileName, $createDate, $createDate, $themeTags, $zero);
        $stmt->execute();
        printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Same question asked here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057954/get-last-insert-id-after-a-prepared-insert-with-pdo

Comment: thanks, I tried to search for this but didn't know it was called PDO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using PDO, [here's how to get that](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

```
PDO::lastInsertId()
```

If using mysqli, [try this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```
mysqli::$insert_id
```

Comment: when I do `$storyID = $db->lastInsertId('story_id');` I get the following error: `Call to a member function lastInsertId() on a non-object`

Comment: use `$this->db->lastInsertId('story_id');`

Comment: hmm, I guess I'm using mysqli not PDO.

Comment: if that's the case, than you want to see this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: I figured it out, its `$stmt->insert_id;` for mysqli. you pointed me in the right direction so thanks!

Comment: sorry if this is off-topic but is PDO recommended over mysqli?

Comment: yes, if sometime in the future you want to support another database.