# PHP lastInsertId() - returns the previous record number

Tags: php, pdo, auto-increment

I have the following code (removed the actual data) and it successfully writes a record into my table.

```
$db = new database('db_name');
$sql='INSERT INTO table (fieldshere);';
$pds=$db->pdo->prepare($sql);
$pds->execute(array(datahere));

$_SESSION['userid'] = $db->pdo->lastInsertId();
```

The problem I'm having is its returning the previous record number - eg: if it has just written record number 100 it returns number 99.

I can see auto increment on the table row number and this appears normal. eg: if table row is currently 100 then auto increment says 101 (for the next row).

The table started at number 0 but still not sure if this would be any issue.

Any thing is the table has a userid column which has auto increment on it and this is the number I need.

Is there any reason why I would be getting the previous row number?

thx

Comment: Have you tried using the name paramater within lastInsertId()? e.g. `lastInsertId('userid');` - sorry if that doesn't work... a bit of a shot in the dark

Comment: what database platform are you using? MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using postgreSQL, you might have the same probleme posted here :
[Get last insert id after a prepared insert with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057954/get-last-insert-id-after-a-prepared-insert-with-pdo)

you probably should specify the "name" parameter of the lastInsertId() method : "Name of the sequence object from which the ID should be returned."